# Angular filter if value not matched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter

I have an array `data`, I want to filter it into two array.
One if `id==100` and second if `id!=100`

```
$scope.if100 = $filter('filter')(data, { id: 100 })[0];
$scope.ifnot100 = ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` method from **native** javascript.

The **filter()** method creates a new `array` with all elements that pass the test implemented by the **callback** provided function.

```
$scope.if100=$scope.data.filter(function(item){
     return item==100;
});
$scope.ifnot100=$scope.data.filter(function(item){
     return !(item==100);
});
```

or from `angularjs` by passing a `callback` function.

```
$scope.if100 = $filter('filter')(data, function(item){ return item.id == 100;});
$scope.ifnot100 = $filter('filter')(data, function(item){ return item.id != 100;});
```

Comment: isn't is $filter?

Comment: This is from javascript native.